# C++ Code in function as argument

Tags: c++, function, arduino

I have this code:

```
void longitudeChanged() {
  Serial.println("Longitude: " + String(GpsLon.value,8));
}
```

in main:

```
  GpsLon.onUpdate(longitudeChanged);
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
GpsLon.onUpdate({
  Serial.println("Longitude: " + String(GpsLon.value,8));
});
```

(Like I do in Java script!);
but this is not the rigth way. How to do it?

Tnx

Erik

Comment: What is exactly is the point of this? You're not supposed to do it like this, at all.

Comment: @Link How is it supposed to be done?

Comment: Look at @OMGTechy's response

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Behold, the mighty lambda!

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void myFunction(T t) {
    t();
}

int main() {
    myFunction([](){ std::cout << "Hi!" << std::endl; });
}
```

[If you'd like to learn more about them, take a look here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

To decrypt this a little, here's a breakdown:

- You have a function that takes another function via a template argument.
- That function does nothing other than call its argument.
- Inside of main, you call that function with a lambda as its argument.
- The lambda can be broken into three parts `[]` (the capture, don't worry too much about that for now) `()` the function arguments, in this case there are none) and `{ ... }` (the body, just like any other function).

So the lambda part is just this:

```
[](){ std::cout << "Hi!" << std::endl; }
```

Here's another example of a lambda that takes an int and returns double its value:

```
[](int value){ return value * 2; }
```

Comment: Yes  - this was what I was looking for.

Thank you.